# Blur event doesn't work as expected on input file

Tags: javascript

I have this script that is design to execute a function when you click outside of the targeted element hence the simple solution is to use the blur event. I used

blur on the input file and it is not working how I expect it to work. This is what I notice when I click on the input file, it instantly execute the function. How can I

prevent that? I want to be able to click on the input file element and then click any where that is outside of that input file element to be able to execute the

targeted function. If it's not possible with the blur method then what other methods can I use to do something like that?

```js
document.querySelector('#x').addEventListener('blur',fx);

function fx(){
  alert('ok')
}
```

```html
<input id='x' type='file'>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Usually when you use blur on a targeted element that you clicked on then you click outside of that targeted element it suppose to execute something  but in that code example that I provided it does not do that I notice as soon as you click on the targeted element it instantly executes the function.

Comment: what are you wanting to detect? when the user closes the `input` dialog window? or when the user selects a different tab or window altogether? i mean, those are the only ways that the `input` dialog window will lose "focus"

Answer (score 0):

The event is triggered immediately since the `input` element blurs if either the window dialog opens or you let go of your mouse while the cursor is on top of the button because the `input` element ***is*** the button.

You will have to write your own custom function that deals with that scenario. `window.addEventListener('blur', blur)` and `window.addEventListener('focus', focus)` may be useful to this end.

FWIW, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) is a list of every single JS event.